# What is happening with React's binding of this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to unearth the cause of some strange behavior in the binding of `this` in a React component.

I'm used to developing components and placing their methods in the class body and binding them to the component's `this` within the `constructor`. However, I recently decided I wanted to clean things up and separate concerns by extracting some of these large methods to separate files, and then importing them into the component.

To my dismay, binding `this` does not work as easy in this case. Even stranger, while the use of an ES6 arrow function seems to not bind properly, the use of a basic ES5 function is working fine. I'm trying to figure out the cause of this behavior:

Example 1 [WORKS AS EXPECTED]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      name: 'John'
    };
  }

  changeName() {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      name: 'Jane'
    });
  }
...
```

Example 2 [NOT WORKING -- TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined]

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import changeName from './change-name';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.changeName = changeName.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      name: 'John'
    };
  }
...
```

`change-name.js`

```
const changeName = () => {
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    name: 'Jane'
  });
};

export default changeName;
```

Example 3 [WORKS AS EXPECTED -- Same `App.js` as Example 2]

`change-name.js`

```
function changeName() {
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    name: 'Jane'
  });
};

module.exports = changeName;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is a correct arrow function behavior.

See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. Arrow functions are always anonymous. These function
>   expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot
>   be used as constructors.

This part **does not bind its own this** is the one you are asking about. Arrow function takes `this` from the context that *surrounds* this function declaration.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. I was under the impression declaring a `const` arrow function is synonymous with an ES5 function. Thanks!

Comment: So within the React component's constructor function why does `this.changeN = changeName` not give the imported function its `this`? Assuming `changeName` is the imported function (defined as an arrow function).

Comment: because the changeName function implementation explicitly takes it from the environment where it is declared. Think of it as of normal function but bound to the outer `this`: `changeName.bind(this)` where `this` is the `this` of the place of the arrow function declaration

Answer (score 3):

This is new es6 function style. You dont need to bind your methid if you are using es6 arrow function.

Remove binding statement from constructor and it should work.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe it was that simple. Although I do still need to bind `this` to the method when I use it within the component like so `<button onClick={changeName.bind(this)}>Change Name</button>` (which leaves me still confused as to why binding within the constructor isn't working) ... but nonetheless that's a good enough solution for me! Thanks

Comment: Function context are always defined while calling the function. If you dont use bind on onClick attr. then it will take window as its contextcontext which will throw error.

Comment: Not for arrow functions. Arrow functions resolve `this` lexically.

Comment: @aware what I can't believe is that you accept the answer which is way less descriptive and is given later than mine

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this syntax. It works perfectly fine without any binding:

```
class Something extends React.Component {
    changeName = () => {
        // Works
    }

    render() {
        // Add input, div or something with onChange or onClick
    }
}

export default Something
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I'm already aware of that being available. I was looking for a way to keep the `changeName` method in a separate file and import it into the component(s) it's being used in.